# Remove primary key(s) - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I cannot seem to be able to delete primary keys in a table.
All references (FKs) have been removed but it still doesn't let me delete it.

What I'm trying to do is: delete old primary keys to add a new one - but keep the old columns and data (just remove the PK attribute).

**What is wrong ?**

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `User` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Company` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  --unrelated boolean fields
  PRIMARY KEY (`User`,`Company`),
  KEY `FK_Employee_Company_idx` (`Company`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Employee_Company` FOREIGN KEY (`Company`) REFERENCES `company` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Employee_User` FOREIGN KEY (`User`) REFERENCES `user` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Trying to delete:

```
alter table Employee
drop primary key;
```

Issue:

> Error 1025: Error on rename of '.\DB_NAME#sql-3640_4' to '.\DB_NAME\employee' (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") SQL Statement: ALTER TABLE `DB_NAME`.`employee`  DROP PRIMARY KEY

Nothing references this table anymore. I also checked via statements which select from `information_schema.key_column_usage` but yields no results.

Wasted the last hours on Google but can't seem to figure it out.

---

*And if that would work, adding a new column:*

```
alter table Employee
add column ID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key;
```

Comment: Try adding an index on `(User, Company)` before dropping the constraint.  It's possible you need an index to satisfy one or more FK constraints.

Comment: You must find all tables which refers to `employee` table and remove according FKs from their structures.

Comment: @Blacktempel In general we don't know the expression of external FK which may differ from one of the PK in this table.

Comment: Notice, if we remove or comment out FK_Employee_User in the employee table, that is the FK requiring the index.  : )   `https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=87dbc7e42389762c4c95ee332686cbec`

Comment: @JonArmstrong Which then would not solve it, as the outgoing FK has to stay and modification is done with a filled DB table. Anyway it's done now. :)

Comment: Sorry. I didn't mean commenting out that FK is the solution.  I just meant that shows which FK is the issue, not a FK in another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index is still needed for the existing FK constraints.

Adding the following index (first) should satisfy that requirement:

```
CREATE INDEX xxx ON employee (User, Company);
```

[Test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=33a25ee2942d89a02102138327fedaa9)

Comment: I was able to do it by adding a missing index for `User` as `Company` already had one.
`alter table Employee
add index FK_Employee_User_idx (User ASC);`

Comment: That's right.  In this case, only the index on (User) is required (for this issue), since it was the employee FK referring to the user table that was the issue.